# SQL comma delimited list in select clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, subquery

I have the following tables

Table A

```
--------------------------
part no  description
-----------------------
001      Brake
002      Clutch
003      Alternator
```

Table B

```
--------------------------
Vehicle_id  brand  Part_No
-----------------------
42          Honda        001
34          Toyota       002
42          Honda        003
34          Toyota       001
```

I want to write a query that will return the following

```
Vehicle_id   brand    parts
42           Honda    Brake,Alternator
```

Any ideas

Comment: How do you come up with the result?

Comment: What database are you using for running this query. Also, please elaborate on what are you trying to achieve. In your result you are showing vehicle_id 34 and brand as Honda whereas in table b there are two records for vehicle_id 34 and the corresponding brand for both these records is Toyota.

Comment: sorry. Corrected output. I want to display one to many records in one distinct field from the right table

Comment: Using MSSQL Server 2008

Comment: try this http://skillfulness.blogspot.in/2012/06/how-to-simulate-mysql-groupconcat.html

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
SELECT B.VID,
  B.BRND,
  WMSYS.WM_CONCAT(A.DESCP) PARTS
FROM
  (SELECT 001 prtno,'Brake' Descp FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 002 prtno,'Clutch' Descp FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 003 prtno,'Alternator' Descp FROM dual
  )a,
  (SELECT 42 VID,'Honda' Brnd,001 prt_no FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 34 VID,'Toyota' Brnd,002 prt_no FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 42 VID,'Honda' Brnd,003 prt_no FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 34 VID,'Toyota' Brnd,001 prt_no FROM dual
  )b
WHERE A.PRTNO = B.PRT_NO GROUP BY B.VID,
  B.BRND;
```

Comment: won't this actually create more the one row? I need all partnames in one row. More like pivoted.

Comment: This is for oracle RDBMS

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are great.

Comment: No problem buddy. If it helped you could u plz accept the answer